# Sync a frequently changing variable across concurrent processes

Tags: python

Say I have three processes running

- SimonsSubconsious - Randomly deciding whether he wants to say "simon says"
- SimonsGame1 - Giving out commands for game 1
- SimonsGame2 - Giving out commands for game 2

This is an attempt, but it really doesn't do what I need it to, because Game 1 and Game 2 aren't in sync. Simon is making separate random decisions.

**SimonsSubconcious.py**

```
import time
import random
def main():
    while True:
        simon_says = random.randint(0, 1)
        time.sleep(1)
        print(simon_says)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**SimonsGame1.py**

```
import time
from SimonsSubconsious import simon_says
commands = ['jump', 'sit', 'clap']
while True:
    for command in commands:
        print(f"{'Simon says' if simon_says else ''} {command}")
        time.sleep(1)
```

**SimonsGame2.py**

```
import time
from SimonsSubconsious import simon_says
commands = ['bark', 'moo', 'meow']
while True:
    for command in commands:
        print(f"{'Simon says' if simon_says else ''} {command}")
        time.sleep(1)
```

So SimonsSubconsious periodically decides to switch it up, and that needs reflected in both games. If it's "Simon says " for Game 1, I want to ensure it's always "Simon says " for Game 2.

Comment: Just have `simon_says = random.randint(0, 1)` in `SimonsSubconcious.py` without function.

Comment: If you use `multiprocessing` you can use a manager and synchronization primitives or a pipe for this.